# how to add order comment in order pdf?

Tags: magento2.3, sales-order

im new in magento 2,
im work on print order to print order comment when we do print order from front end,

**My Orders->Print Order**

**when we click on Print Order the same comment print on PDF**

as per the below image.
so how can we print that comment on Order PDF?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use

```
<referenceBlock name="additional.product.info">
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
                   name="order.comment"
                   template="Namespace_Sales::order/order_comment.phtml"
                   cacheable="false" />

</referenceBlock>
```

as below is the code for comment xml

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getVisibleStatusHistory() on null in vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/order_comments.phtml:9

its give me this error

Comment: pls let me know on this

Comment: You need to use your block instead of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template and call the order object. or you can use viewModel

Comment: im use in core file, how can i did this in core?

Comment: Can you please paste your code here what you are doing?

Comment: <referenceBlock name="additional.product.info">
   <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"
    name="order.comments"
    template="Magento_Sales::order/order_comments.phtml"
    cacheable="false" />
  </referenceBlock>

Comment: i did only this in sales_order_print.xml file,
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print.xml

Comment: yes but still you need to create your own block dear, how u will get order object without that?

Comment: ok i will do that

Comment: Thanks If you like my support please give be a vote and accept my answer so we can support needed people. also if you are learner and want to improve your magento development you can join my channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCBtRV9tdH-ghtDsjRPcD6pg where you can learn magento in depth

Comment: i have created layout filein my theme Magento_Sales/template and Magento_Sales/layout all have xml file and phtml file

Comment: You need to create a module and add block there please read the tutorial how u can create module.

Comment: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Tms\Printcomment\View\Order\Print
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Tms\Printcomment\View\Order\Print does not exist

Comment: i have created module (Tms_Printcomment), but show me this error

Comment: It looks like 2 case either your file name is wrong or u didn't run compile command , pleas check or paste your complete code here